# How to introduce a code patch into Wix directories.wxs file using cMake

Tags: xml, cmake, wix, windows-installer, cpack

I am using `cMake` with `Wix` to generate my installer executable. I have my executable ready, but I am unable to get a shortcut on the desktop and include my program in the Windows Start menu.
To achieve these two goals, I want to inject some code into the files generated by wix, specifically in the `directories.wxs` file:

```
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
    <Fragment>
        <Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
            <Directory Id="ProgramFiles64Folder">
                <Directory Id="INSTALL_PREFIX_1" Name="myApp">
                    <Directory Id="INSTALL_ROOT" Name="myApp Studio">
                        <Directory Id="CM_DP_MYAPP_RUNTIME.Data" Name="Data">
                            <Directory Id="CM_DP_MYAPP_RUNTIME.Data.ConfigurationFiles" Name="ConfigurationFiles"/>
                        </Directory>
                    </Directory>
                </Directory>
            </Directory>
           <!--CODE MUST BE INJECTED HERE-->
        </Directory>
    </Fragment>
</Wix>
```

The code must be injected where the comment is. The main problem is that a code patch is injected like this:

```
<CPackWiXPatch>
  <CPackWiXFragment Id=XXXX>
      <ComponentRef Id="ApplicationShortcut" />     
      <ComponentRef Id="ApplicationShortcutDesktop" /> 
  </CPackWiXFragment>
</CPackWiXPatch>
```

XXX is the ID of the `xml` tag where the code patch will be injected, in this case it would have to be TARGETDIR. The problem is that if I set the ID as TARGETDIR it returns the following error:

```
Some xml patch fragments did not have matching ids: 'targetdir'
```

Does anyone know how I can specify an id to inject my code at that point?